# How to get IST in Unix if my current timezone is UTC. Also I need to get the time format to be dd/mm/yyyy hr:min:sec?

Tags: date, unix, unix-timestamp

I have just started learning about the date command in Unix.
I have typed the below code to get the IST. But I don't know how to convert it to a specific format.

> TZ = IST-5:30 date

This gives the result as Thu Feb 10:31:51 IST 2022.

But I want the output to be 03/02/2022 10:31:51 IST.

Is there any way to get the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With date (GNU coreutils) 8.32 you can use the +FORMAT argument:

```
TZ=IST-5:30 date +'%d/%m/%y %T %Z'
03/02/22 10:46:50 IST
```

`%x` would be a better choice instead of `%d/%m/%y` if your locale allows for it.

Comment: If I add the +Format arguments to my statement, then I get date:extra operand error. But when I try it on an online compiler, it works.

Comment: You may be using a different date implementation, operating system etc. The tags you used  does not tell us about your environment.  Also it's not a programming question so I voted to close it.  Ask on the superuser community instead.